# Plane vector rotation

Tags: geometry

How do I compute the x,y,z rotations in degrees to move a plane with a normal vector of 0,0,1 (rotate it) so that its normal vector has a new position of 0.508, 0.699, 0.502?

Essentially, I need to move a plane from one location/orientation to another, about the x, y, z axes.  The staring and ending positions of the normal vector this plane are known (noted above).

Comment: Normally you would say "rotate a plane" meaning that the plane is mapped to itself, so the normal would not change (or at least it would wind up collinear with its original normal.)  If you want to rotate a plane around an arbitrary axis, then your problem is underspecified: there would be *lots* of rotations that do that. Can you clarify if any of those rotations would do, or if you're looking for something more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a tranformation matrix.  You have decribed what we will do to (0,0,1)

But what will we do to $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)?$

There is not a unique transformation that takes $(0,0,1)$ to $(0.508, 0.699, 0.502)$

To keep the transformation rigid (one the preserves angle measures and distances) we will need to find unit vectors that are orthogonal to $(0.508, 0.699, 0.502)$

$(-0.699, 0.508,0)$ will be orthogonal to $(0.508, 0.699, 0.502)$

If we divide the vector by its norm, (i.e. $\sqrt {0.699^2 + 0.508^2}$ we will have one ortho-normal vector.

And if we take the cross product of these two vectors we will get a third ortho-normal vector.

$\pmatrix {0.295 & -0.809 & 0.508\\0.406&0.588&0.699\\-0.864&0&0.502}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$

Will rotate any point and rotate $(0,0,1)$ to the desired location.

Comment: This helped immensely, thanks...I’m able to use this matrix to get angles

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a plane with a normal vector of (0,0,1) rotates so that the normal vector has a new position of (0.508, 0.699, 0.502)?

In this case, the new normal vector (0.508, 0.699, 0.502) show the directional cosines $(\theta_x,\theta_y,\theta_z)$, so your requests are $\frac{180}{\pi}(\arccos(0.508),\arccos(0.699),\arccos(0.502))$.

Hope it helps...